# Laravel File Uploads: Accessing the file from server

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5

I have successfully uploaded the image files to the server using Laravel 5.0. Here is my form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uploads</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'uploadProcessing' , 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
        {!! Form::label('image','Upload Image') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image') !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function uploadProcessing() {
    $image = Input::file('image');
    $imageName = rand(1111, 9999) . '.' . Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Input::file('image')->move(base_path() . '/public/uploads/', $imageName);
}
```

Along with that, I am saving the `$imageName` as a refrence in database table.
Now I have to display that image in a view with that reference. I am trying to access it in this way:

```
@foreach($result as $r)
{!! HTML::image('uploads/$r->reference') !!}
@endforeach
```

But it is not working, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, It was simple, I tried this:

```
<img src="..\uploads\{!! $r->reference !!}" />
```

And it worked

Comment: It's better to use asset helper : try  `<img src="{{ asset('uploads\'.$r->reference') }}" />`